# Ajax post error

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, ajax, jquery

I want to post data to a web service with ajax. there is my ajax code:

```
 function Looping() {
        var Grid = document.getElementById("<%= gvHastalar.ClientID %>");
        var Row;
        var Cell;
        if (Grid.rows.length > 2) {
            for (i = 1; i < Grid.rows.length - 1; i++) {
                Row = Grid.rows[i];
                Cell = Row.cells[3];
                alert(Cell.innerHTML);
                var html = $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost:7753/HastaTahlilUyariServisi.asmx/f_HastaninAktarilacakAlislabTestleri",
                    data: "{_sTcKimlikNo:" + Cell.innerHTML + ",_iKlinikKodu:18001,_bAy:12,_iYil:2009}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: alert('success'),
                    error: alert('error')
                }
                ).responseText;
                Row.style.backgroundColor = "#D3EFD1";
            }
        }
    }
```

And my webservice function's code is here:

```
 [WebMethod]
    [SoapHeader("_ticket", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.In)]//SoapHeaderDirection.Out
    public DataSet f_HastaninAlisLabTahlilleri(string _sTcKimlikNo, int _iKlinikKodu, byte _bAy, int _iYil)
    {
        try
        {
            string QSelect =
                               @"SELECT * FROM [V_EUCLID_SONUC]
                                 WHERE  MONTH(KAYITTARIHI) = " + _bAy + @"
                                   AND YEAR(KAYITTARIHI) = " + _iYil +
                                   AND TCKIMLIKNO = '" + _sTcKimlikNo + @"'";

            return dbA.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.Text, QSelect);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
    }
```

There is a break point on function which is in the web service but debug never go that break point. I pasted webservice's url from browser but may be url is wrong. And when i run project, i have 3 alert.
First Cell's text its normal.Second alert is *success* and the last alert is *error*. I want to send parameters to f_HastaninAlisLabTahlilleri and user return dataset. How can i do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few remarks about your code:

1. `success` and `error` are callback functions, they should be defined like this:

   ```
   success: function(data) { alert('success'); },
   error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('error'); }
   ```
2. ASMX web services use `SOAP` by default unless you decorate them with [ScriptServiceAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute.aspx) in which case `JSON` could be used to invoke a method. It is not clear from your code if the web service is decorated with this attribute.
3. When you pass parameters, you need to encode them, use `JSON. stringify` instead of concatenating strings:

   ```
   data: JSON.stringify({_sTcKimlikNo: Cell.innerHTML, 
                         _iKlinikKodu: 18001,
                         _bAy: 12,_iYil: 2009});
   ```

Use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to inspect network AJAX requests and server responses and post them on StackOverflow to facilitate debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a break-point in the web-service code i.e. even the IDE would not let u debug the web-service code.... it is an old legacy the VS.Net IDE has since its inception... lets see if it is resolved in VS 2010.

Comment: What? Untrue. For instructions, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0twaftwz.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

The url that you have specified in the JQuery script is not equal to the name of the function in c# code. Isn't it the point. *f_HastaninAktarilacakAlislabTestleri* in url and *f_HastaninAlisLabTahlilleri* in c# code. Some reasons for such a problem can be wrong url or deference between argument list of client request and argument list of the server side method or action.